# Double connection in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

My question is very simple. I have a Node.js server with the following code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connection');
});
```

My web page contains just

```
var socket = io();
```

I open the app in one window. Then I open it in another. The console shows three connections. If I refresh one of the windows, the console shows a total of six connections. I refresh once more, I get 10 connections. Once more, 15 connections.

How is that possible? I would like one connection per page load, how can I achieve that.

Thanks for your attention!

NB: I don't know if it is important, but I am also using Express, Mysql and sessions

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins which might be sending additional requests?

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the io.on() outside my app.get().

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem  instead of io.on('connection')
just use

io.once('connect')

**EDIT**:   here is code

```
io.once('connect', function (socket) {
console.log('connection');
});
```